# Insert Error Message column based on null columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, null-check

I have a table created below.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_NULL
(
ID INT,
NAME VARCHAR(10),
PLACE VARCHAR(10),
ADDRESS VARCHAR(10),
ERRORMESSAGE VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO TEST_NULL
VALUES
(1, 'ABC', 'BLR', 'WHT', NULL),
(2, 'DEF', 'BLR', NULL, NULL),
(3, 'GHI', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(4, 'JKL', NULL, 'WHT', NULL)

SELECT * FROM TEST_NULL
```

When I do a select for the table, I want the expected result for the ERRORMESSAGE column as below.

I need to get the 1st record as:

```
1, 'ABC', 'BLR', 'WHT', NULL
```

I need to get the 2nd record as:

```
2, 'DEF', 'BLR', NULL, 'Address is NULL'
```

I need to get the 3rd record as:

```
3, 'GHI', NULL, NULL, 'Place, Address is NULL'
```

I need to get the 4th record as:

```
4, 'JKL', NULL, 'WHT', 'Place is NULL'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a `CASE` expression to generate the error message is the cleanest way to go here:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, PLACE, ADDRESS,
       CASE WHEN PLACE IS NULL AND ADDRESS IS NULL THEN 'Place, Address is NULL'
            WHEN PLACE IS NULL                     THEN 'Place is NULL'
            WHEN ADDRESS IS NULL                   THEN 'Address is NULL'
            ELSE NULL END
FROM TEST_NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have tried this, but I have a lot of fields to check and also this seems kind of hardcoded. So I was looking for some function which can take care of this?

Comment: Oracle has a `DECODE` function which can do what you want, but SQL Server does not have it.  If you poke around for an alternative, mostly you will find a `CASE` expression as the recommendation.

Comment: Sure Tim. For now let me go ahead with this approach. In case you come across any optimal way, please feel free to share it across. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Case` clause:-

```
SELECT ID,NAME,PLACE,ADDRESS, case 

            when
                PLACE is not null and ADDRESS is not null 
            then null 
            when 
                PLACE is null and ADDRESS is not null 
            then 'PLACE is NULL'
            when 
                PLACE is not null and ADDRESS is null 
            then 'ADDRESS is NULL'
            when 
                PLACE is null and ADDRESS is  null 
            then 'PLACE, Address is NULL'
            end as ERRORMESSAGE  

FROM TEST_NULL
```

**Result:-**

```
ID  NAME    PLACE   ADDRESS ERRORMESSAGE
1   ABC     BLR      WHT        NULL
2   DEF     BLR     NULL    ADDRESS is NULL
3   GHI     NULL    NULL    PLACE, Address is NULL
4   JKL    NULL      WHT    PLACE is NULL
```

Comment: The solution works fine for 3 to 4 columns, but I have 14 columns to check for and this doesn't seem to be feasible for 14 columns. Any function that I can use?

Comment: The above table was just a sample I created to explain my problem. I actually have a table with 14 columns to check for null values and concatenate the error message to a single column.